# mathematical limits in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to do mathematical limits in python.

I have defined a function for smoke

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()

def drawsmoke(y):
    i = 0
    while i < ((2 * y) - 1):
        t.seth(i * 5)
        t.circle((10 + i), 160)
        i = i + 2
```

this draws one side of the smoke, the other side yet to be done.

now the problem arises when i try to draw about 4 smoke circles(y=4) that the smoke starts turning the wrong way. to fix this, i considered doing a mathematical limit. I would make a variable

```
   smkang=(i*5)
```

and then do a limit on this variable:

```
      lim
    smkang->20
```

how may i do this? or is there another way not involving limits? btw this is in turtle (python language but turtle imported)
thanks

Comment: What is `t`? Please have a look at http://sscce.org/, where 'sc' is sef contained and 'c' "correct"/"compilable"(/"working")

Comment: i have imported turtle at the start

        import turtle
        t = turtle.Pen()
well yeah, t is turtle.Pen()

Comment: ok, I edited your question in order to make it complete.

Comment: ok thanks i should have probably done that at the start

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is the constant angle of 160 degrees at the circle. As the starting angle is a `f(i)`, the ending one should be as well... I'll think about it, but maybe someone finds another solution.

Comment: yes this seems to help a bit
i tried 160-i, it doesnt work very well, but ill be able to find a better one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html). SymPy is a Python library for symbolic mathematics. It aims to become a full-featured computer algebra system (CAS) while keeping the code as simple as possible in order to be comprehensible and easily extensible. SymPy is written entirely in Python and does not require any external libraries. Ex:

```
>>> from sympy import limit, Symbol, sin, oo
>>> x = Symbol("x")
>>> limit(sin(x)/x, x, 0)
1
```